# Post image in WordPress not appearing on home page

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, post-meta

I just installed WordPress and I'm trying to set a image to every post I have.

I did this:

Custom fields ----name: paddimage-gallery --value: URL of image.

I go to my home page and it does not appear.

Example of a page were it does work: [MAIMPOK THEME](http://maimpok-template.blogspot.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there you just need to call it inside your theme file
say in your index.php
inside the loop somewhere between

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
 ///
 ///
<?php endwhile; // End the loop. ?>
```

you need to add a call for that image using get_post_meta()
like this:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
   $img_src = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'paddimage-gallery', true);
   if (isset($img_src){
     echo '<img src=' . $img_src . '>';
   }
   ///
<?php endwhile; // End the loop. ?>
```

Hope this Helps.